# Unable to execute Get-NLBClusterNode remotely powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, load-balancing

I've created a small cluster of 2 win servers in a domain and another for the remote executions.

- I am able to run Get-NlbClusterNode locally on each of the servers.
- I can establish remote session with the 2 nodes and have all the permissions in place.
- I can run  Get-NlbClusterNode command remotely if only one of the servers is in the cluster, but when both are in the cluster I get:

```
    PS C:\Windows\system32> Invoke-Command -ComputerName 10.10.10.9 -ScriptBlock { Get-NlbClusterNode } -credential $Creds
    Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
        + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (Microsoft.Netwo...tNlbClusterNode:GetNlbClusterNode) [Get-NlbClusterN
       ode], UnauthorizedAccessException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Access denied.,Microsoft.NetworkLoadBalancingClusters.PowerShell.GetNlbClusterNode
        + PSComputerName        : 10.10.10.9
```

Is this the so called powershell double hop issue? How could be this fixed?

Thank you

Comment: NLB configuration is off-topic, unless there's a programming issue. Try ServerFault instead. That being said, is the IP in the question node's own address or NLB's virtual one?

Comment: @vonPryz thank you for the info.
thats the node's ip address